# default wordpress htaccess causing redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, loops, redirect, cpanel

I have default wordpress htaccess on my wordpress sites.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I'm using cpanel on server and wordpress is installed in /home/username/public_html
For some reason when I access some site on the website that does not exists I get internal server error instead of 404.

Also in log I get this error

```
 Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace
```

And after some time I start to get this error

```
mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5
```

which in the end disables my webpage with message about not enough resources.

I'm using whm/cpanel with apache.  Anyone knows  how to fix this ?

Comment: What version of wordpress are you using? And are you using a subdomain, subfolder or regular site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of the path you provided for your install directory, I'm going to assume you are using the default setup at `www.yousite.com`.
The problem looks like you are using the `htaccess` rules for a `wordpress` site installed on a `subdomain` and **not** the default rules.

You should try and use the default wordpress rules below instead.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

You can see here the different htaccess configurations to use for certain types of WP installs.
http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Wordpress has a lot of internal stuff that works with htaccess so I would try and use the recommended htaccess configs.